# xpath for obtaining button within a row

Tags: python, unit-testing, selenium, xpath, splinter

I writing some browser tests with splinter and have a page with clearly-defined rows containing their own titles, buttons, etc. Something like:

[image]

In my particular case, I can obtain a single row as follows:

```
row = lambda title: browser.find_by_xpath("//div[@class='my-row'][contains(., '{0}')]".format(title))

row1 = row('Row 1')
row2 = row('Row 2')
```

Then, with this lamba:

```
button = lambda elmt, text: elmt.find_by_xpath("//a[@class='btn'][contains(.,'{0}')]".format(text))
```

I could hone in on the correct regular button or say something like:

```
assert button(row1, 'Special button')
assert not button(row2, 'Special button')
```

But when I call the button lambda, it returns buttons from other rows.

From my understanding, finding by xpath via this lamba says, "starting from elmt, look for buttons *nested within elmt* that contain the given text". Since I am getting stuff from other rows not nested within the current one, though, what am I missing here?

What is wrong with my xpath?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XPath expressions that start with `//` start at the *root* node of the document, and select nodes regardless of their position in the document. The current context node of such an expression, for example

```
//div
```

has no effect on the result set that is returned. To search the `//` (descendant-or-self::) axis starting from the context node, you need to use

```
.//div
```

In your case, this means changing

```
button = lambda elmt, text: elmt.find_by_xpath("//a[@class='btn'][contains(.,'{0}')]".format(text))
```

to

```
button = lambda elmt, text: elmt.find_by_xpath(".//a[@class='btn'][contains(.,'{0}')]".format(text))
```

(Caveat: That's all concerning the XPath expressions in your code, I cannot comment on the rest.)